# Tem como aceitar um pull request localmente? Via terminal ou GitHub desktop?

Tags: git, github

Consigo aceitar o pull request aberto localmente, via terminal ou GitHub desktop.

Comment: Até onde eu sei Pull Request não são exatamente do git, e sim de agregadores como GitHub, GitLab, etc... O GitHub tem uma [ferramenta por linha de comando](https://hub.github.com/) que pode te ajudar.

Comment: Quando vc diz aceitar se refere avaliar as alteração e "mergear" com a branch master via git? Ou vc se refere a comentar nas linhas que precisam ser melhoradas, isto é, realizar code review?

Comment: adicionando aos comentários acima, "aceitar o pull request" nada mais é que fazer merge do branch origem com o branch destino, o pull request é apenas um conceito ou uma função que existe ou não onde seu source foi guardado, ou seja, um pull request não existe dentro do git só no programa que você usa para controlar, imagina se você faz um servidor git sem interação visual, como faria um pull request? criei uma feature saindo do develop, fiz a feature e quero devolver por meio de pull request, então eu faço um push e aviso a galera que tem um fetch aguardando merge no develop, isso é um PR

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Primeiro vamos definir [pra que serve o `pull request`](https://help.github.com/pt/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/about-pull-requests)

> As pull requests permitem que você informe outras pessoas sobre as alterações das quais você fez `push` para um `branch` em um repositório no GitHub. Depois que uma `pull request` é aberta, você pode discutir e revisar as possíveis alterações com colaboradores e adicionar `commits` de acompanhamento antes que as alterações sofram `merge` no `branch` base.

Com base nessa afirmação: como aceitar um pull request localmente? **Via terminal**:
A Resposta é Sim.

Vamos assumir como interação as `branchs`: `master` e `new-branch`. Uma vez o `pull request` (PR) da `new-branch` criado, e pode ser [via git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6235379/how-to-send-pull-request-on-git), para aceitar o PR na `master` siga os passos:

1. Atualize seu ramo local baixando objetos e referências de outro repositório, isto é, quer enxergar `new-branch` recém criado com base na `master`, basta digitar o comando [gti fetch -pt](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch);
2. Para visualizar as alterações que a `new-branch` irá causar na `master` utilize o comando `git diff`. Neste caso queremos fazer o `code review` das alterações e ver a diferença entre as duas `branchs`, aplique o comando `git diff master..new-branch`;
3. Após análise, faça o merge na master: `git merge new-branch`. Obs.: Vc deve estar na `master` para executar este comando.
4. Agora restando apenas enviar as alterações para o remoto: `git push origin master`. Seu PR passará do status `OPEN` para `MERGED`.

Veja o teste na sequencia. Refiz o processo descrito anteriormente e funcionou como tivesse aceitado o PR.

Segue Imagens
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sobre realizar o processo via Github desktop, nunca utilizei, somente linha de comando, então não tenho propriedade para falar.